# How do I make it so I can have social icons on the left, logo in centre and navigation on the right?

Tags: html, css, navigation

Currently I have my website with the logo in the middle and the navigation on the right as shown below. However I want it to have social icons on the left, logo in the middle, and navigation on the right, therefore how do I do this ? I keep trying and failing.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

HTML

```
   <div id="nav-div">
        <ul>
            <h1>JOSH TAYLOR</h1>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#nav-div {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 15px;
    }

#nav-div h1{
color: lightskyblue;
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 30px;
float: left;
margin-left: 460px;
width: 200px;
}

#nav-div h1:hover{
color: white;
transition:all 0.40s;
}

#nav-div ul{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background: ;
line-height: 80px;
border-bottom: px solid black;
}

#nav-div ul a{
text-decoration: none;
color: lightskyblue;
padding: 25px;
}

#nav-div ul a:hover{
color:white;
transition:all 0.40s;
font-style:italic;
}

#nav-div ul li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
font-style:normal; 
font-size: 13px;
margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Flexboxes will solve this

Comment: I think there some code missing. I see no social icons

Comment: ...or a logo come to that.

Answer (score 0):

Using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you can have a flex `div` or `header` and enclose the three elements within and give it a `justify-content:space-around` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g64a7jz/5/) the rest is for presentation purpose. Hope this helps.

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex .social{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex .social li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.flex nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex nav ul li{
   display: inline-block;
}

.flex nav ul li a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="flex">
  <ul class="social">
    <li>SOCIAL</li>
    <li>SOCIAL</li>
    <li>SOCIAL</li>
  </ul>
  
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Bootstrap and enclose all three in a div with class row and add the class col-md-4 to all sub-divs(if you want a better result for mobile users replace md with xs).

Comment: @Daniel You're right. It's Bootstrap. I will edit my answer.